# convert sqlite data to json using php

Tags: php, json, sqlite

I'm trying to convert sqlite query into json. I have the following table with two columns name and age. When I print the query the format doesn't seem to be correct. why am I getting an extra key value pair?

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('info.db');

$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM info');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {

    $jsonArray[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($jsonArray)
?>
```

output

```
[{"0":"billy","name":"billy","1":"20","age":"20"}]
```

desired output

```
    [{"name":"billy","age":"20"}]
```

Comment: fetchArray grabs both association and numerical array indexes. It defaults to SQLITE3_BOTH, use either SQLITE3_ASSOC or SQLITE3_NUM instead.

Comment: cloud916  check and try answer given below and let us know if any-one worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change query to get only those column which are required:

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT name,age FROM info'); 
// if you want all column then only use *
```

And then use `SQLITE3_ASSOC`

```
while($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
```

Reference:- [SQLite3Result::fetchArray](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php)

***Parameters***

> ***mode***
>
> Controls how the next row will be returned to the caller. This
> value must be one of either SQLITE3_ASSOC, SQLITE3_NUM, or
> SQLITE3_BOTH.
>
> ***SQLITE3_ASSOC***: returns an array indexed by column name as returned in
> the corresponding result set
>
> ***SQLITE3_NUM***: returns an array indexed by column number as returned in
> the corresponding result set, starting at column 0
>
> ***SQLITE3_BOTH***: returns an array indexed by both column name and number
> as returned in the corresponding result set, starting at column 0

Answer (score 4):

Follow an example:

```
<?php
    $db = new SQLite3('info.db');
    $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM info');
    $data = array();
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier than all that

```
<?php
  $db = new SQLite3('info.db');
  $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM info');
  $rows->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
  echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

say you can use this if you using pdo

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

$sth is your query